# SQL Server Compact Edition and VB/C#

Tags: .net, ado.net, sql-server-ce

Can anyone provide a clear and simple example of how I can open a SSCE database and query it with a SELECT statement? Ultimately I'll need to do this on a system that I have no control over so whatever method/provider I use must be available by default on a standard Windows machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone struggling with this, look at this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983326.aspx

Then it's as simple as this:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try

        Using conn As New SqlCeConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=c:\Reporting.Database.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;"
            conn.Open()
            MsgBox("opened")
            conn.Close()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Sample code here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/07/getting-started-with-sql-server-compact.html
and information on private deployment here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.  you will have to add a reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe and create a using statement for it.

```
    string connectionString = "my connection string";
    string queryString = "select column from mytable where mycolumn = 'somevalue'";    
    using (var cnn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
                        {
                            using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(queryString, cnn))
                            {
                                cnn.Open();

                                var da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
                                var ds = new DataSet();
                                da.Fill(ds);

                            }
                        }
```

You can also use `cmd.Parameters.Add` after you call `cnn.Open();` to add parameters to your query.

Comment: I don't show `System.Data.SqlServerCe` when trying to add a reference to my project.

Comment: what version of visual studio are you using?  do you have sql server ce installed on the dev machine?

Comment: As usual, this is ridiculously complicated. I found the DLL and added a reference to it. When I try to open a connection to the database I get "unable to load the native components... blah blah blah." I followed the KB article instructions and installed both 32 and 64 bit versions of SSCE (they were already installed bc the installer only offered repair or remove) and the error remains.

Comment: are you on 64-bit?  if so, this article may help - http://tech.avivo.si/2009/04/systemdatasqlserverce35-not-installed/